# Filtering with wildcards

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

How can I  use wildcards to filter a result to be like this using `Get-ChildItem | Where-Object`?

```
ApplicationName 20XX - English
```

Whatever wildcard or operator (`-match`, `-like`, `-eq`) I use, it returns nothing, or something more than I want.

Basically, I just want the numbers to be 'wildcarded' to search for 2017-2020, and the rest of the string to be static. Is that possible?

My thought was something like, but unfortunally I cannot get it to work:

```
Where-Object DisplayName -eq 'Application 20[17-20] - English'   
Where-Object DisplayName -Match 'Application 20%% - English'   
Where-Object DisplayName -eq 'Application 20* - English'
```

The importance here is to only have the numbers to be relative.

Note: `Get-WMIobject` is not preferred in this setting unfortunately.

Comment: You are using the wrong format for `-match`.  If you use a standard regular expression, it should do what you want.  For example: `'Application 2019 - English' -match 'Application 20\d{2} - English'`

Comment: Alternatively, `-match '...[12][0-7] - E...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-like is for wildcards.  The simplest would be:

```
Where-Object DisplayName -like 'Application 20* - English'
```

Or in regex:

```
Where-Object DisplayName -match 'Application 20.* - English'   
Where-Object DisplayName -match 'Application 20.. - English'
```

You could try -path with get-childitem:  (-filter doesn't support the square brackets)

```
get-childitem -path 'Application 20[1-2][07-9] - English'   
get-childitem -path 'Application 20* - English'   
get-childitem -path 'Application 20?? - English'   
get-childitem -filter 'Application 20* - English'   
get-childitem -filter 'Application 20?? - English'
```

-filter may be faster, but also matches the short version of the filenames.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen That's unfortunate.  Edited.

Answer (score 3):

With PowerShell wildcard patterns (notice it's the `-like` operator, not `-eq` or `-match`):

```
# matches 2010 through 2029
Where-Object DisplayName -like 'Application 20[1-2][0-9] - English' 

# or, narrowly matching only 2017 through 2020
Where-Object {$_.DisplayName -like 'Application 201[7-9] - English' -or $_.DisplayName -like 'Application 2020 - English'}
```

`-match` on the other hand supports regex, which allows for alternation patterns:

```
Where-Object DisplayName -match 'Application 20(?:1[7-9]|20) - English'
```

I know you mentioned not wanting to offload filtering to WQL, but you *could* if you wanted to:

```
Get-CimInstance -Class Win32_WhateverClassYouQuery -Filter 'DisplayName LIKE "Application 201[7-9] - English" OR DisplayName = "Application 2020 - English"'
```